# How to track and display distance travelled using GPS

Tags: java, android, gps

How would someone attempt to track the distance the user has walked as they are walking- displaying the distance in a text view and updating it accordingly?

It feels confusing looking at all the options there appears to be - Android's Location API and Google's Location Services API to name but two. I've looked through some code that has implemented somewhat similar concepts but I want to understand and know where to start.

Thanks

Comment: Voting to close because your question is a little too broad to belong on StackOverflow. That said, I would (1) register a [`LocationListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) and (2) every time `onLocationChanged` is fired, calculate the distance between the new point and the previous point and then (3) add that to the displayed distance.

Comment: @ElanHamburger - That's fair. Thank you for advice and the help.